# Voltage tolerance of STM32F3xx boot pin

Tags: bootloader, stm32f3

I'm trying to understand the default voltage tolerance of the boot pin(s) used to power up into the system bootloader of an `STM32F3xx`.  I want to power my whole circuit at one voltage (e.g. 7V), and use this same external voltage to set logic high on the boot pin when performing a (hopefully rare) firmware update over USART1.

[AN2602](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/b9/9b/16/3a/12/1e/40/0c/CD00167594.pdf/files/CD00167594.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00167594.pdf)

Comment: Which STM32F3 is it? Different F3 chips have different maximum voltages.

Answer (score 1):

From the datasheet, it looks like `BOOT0` can tolerate up to 9V, so 7V should be OK.

[image]

Comment: Which "whole circuit "?

Comment: I mean as the voltage provided to the BOOT0 pin as well as the voltage provided to a regulator for the MCU and the driver input voltage for a single motor.

Comment: @terabite ah ok then 7V is fine.

Comment: but 0x04: voltage range [2.7 V, 3.6 V] and double word write/erase
operation is used. In this case it is mandatory to supply 9 V
through the VPP pin (refer to the product reference manual for
more details about the double-word write procedure).

Comment: You are looking at an Absolute Maximum, not a recommended condition.  Given that you'll want a pull down anyway to keep the state, you could so easily build a voltage divider.  Just calculate a series resistor for your available supply voltage that in conjunction with the pulldown will target something around the operating voltage, or at least within the chip's design goal of 5v tolerance for the pins not bounded by Vdd.  If you don't want to be prevented from using a lower voltage to drive it, you can put the series resistor in your programming harness.

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75  -- What VPP pin are you talking about???  The STM32F3xx does not have a VPP pin.  The max voltage to a pin(except BOOT0 which is 9V(unless you've got a 373 in which case it is 5.5V)) is 8V (VDD + 4 on the 5V tolerant(so called) pins).  You don't even get that much with a 373, max VDD is 3.6 and max voltage anywhere is 5.5V.  And the 378 does not have the voltage reg, meaning max there is about 1.8V.  I've used everything from F103, L100, L15x, F3xx(303 and 373), F4xx, L4xx, F030 on custom boards and have NEVER seen a VPP.

Comment: See DocID 15687.  @GB-AE7OO

Comment: @Sunnyskyguy EE75 -- I'm going to need a link, because ST does not have such an animal, and google does not return anything useful in the first two pages.  We are talking about STM32 micro's right???

Comment: https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/f7/7e/b9/a8/31/58/41/7b/CD00233952.pdf/files/CD00233952.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00233952.pdf

Comment: That is for F2 series! F3 series seem to not have VPP programming. Recommended operating conditions for BOOT0 is approximately 5.2 to 5.5V, but it really depends on the exact F3 model which is not mentioned, just that it is F3xx. Exact MCU model should always be mentioned!